# access maps v2 with calabash-android

Tags: android-maps-v2, calabash-android

I am currently evaluating calabash for our app. It seems to be very powerful but I haven't found a way to access a Google Map v2 in my native android app. Retrieving the Map via `query` is no problem but I have not found any operations regarding Google Maps v2. Yet there seems to be some kind of support. I found a MapViewUtils class in the calabash-android repository [calabash-android repository](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/test-server/instrumentation-backend/src/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/MapViewUtils.java)

Can someone explain to me how i can access for example the markers on a MapView?

best
Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
When /^I tap the map marker "([^\"]*)"$/ do | marker_title |
  perform_action('tap_map_marker_by_title', marker_title, 60000)
end
```

You can find the supported mapView steps [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/steps/map_steps.rb)

Note, I've not had much look using them myself as my mapview is in a Fragment, so I get a "MapView is not found!” error. According to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/calabash-android/v_hMyRdZnFw/J52QgRSCA8MJ) mapViews in Fragments are not supported yet